# Laravel - Undefined variable: game_code

Tags: laravel, api

I am writing an endpoint for POST Request using the code below:

```
public function unifiedrequest(Request $request)
    {

    // prepare content

    $password = $request->header('Password');
    $username = $request->header('Username');

        $msisdn=$request->msisdn;
        $useresponse=$request->userresponse;
        $useroption=$request->useroption;
        $hash=$request->hash;
        $hash_key="CIA152515276585";

        $data=$msisdn.$useresponse.$useroption.$hash_key;
        $hashed = hash('sha512',$data);
//      return $hashed ;

if($username=="nbfd" && $password=="loka")
{ 
          if($hashed==$hash)
          {
              //implemetation 
             $ref_id=self::gen_uuid();
             $cus_name="greatB";
             $total_amount=456;
             $statuscode="00";
         $statusMsg = "Successful";
             $message="sdssa";
         $data = $total_amount.$statuscode.$statusMsg.$message.$hash_key;
         $hashed = hash('sha512',$data);
//             $hash= $hashed;

             $games = MBFA::where('game_code',$useresponse)->get(); 
                 User_Response::create([
                     'game_code'     =>  $games->game_code,
                     'answer'        =>  $useroption,
                     'msisdn'        =>  $msisdn
                 ]); 


            return response()->json([
             'amount'=>$total_amount,
              'statusCode'=>$statuscode,
               'statusMessage'=>$statusMsg,
                'message'=>$message,
                  'hash'=>$hashed
                ]);

}

    }
```

I expect to see result, but got this error

> Undefined variable: game_code

```
             $games = MBFA::where('game_code',$useresponse)->get(); 
                 User_Response::create([
                     'game_code'     =>  $games->game_code,
                     'answer'        =>  $useroption,
                     'msisdn'        =>  $msisdn
                 ]);
```

Kindly see the code below for the migrations as requested.

```html
CREATE TABLE `BBVA` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_answer1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_option_code1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_option_code2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_option_code3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_option_code4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_option_code5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_answer2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_answer3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_answer4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_answer5` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `thank_you_message` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `header` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `footer` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `user_response`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_response` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `msisdn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount_charged` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_ref` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I just added the tables details

This is where the error is coming from.  Please what could have been the cause and how do I resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing `$games = MBFA::where('game_code',$useresponse)->get();` to `$games = MBFA::where('game_code',$useresponse)->first();`

Comment: Change get() to firstOrFail()

Comment: When I did that, I got a new error:   No query results for model [App\BBVA]

Answer (score 2):

Replace `MBFA::where('game_code',$useresponse)->get();` with `MBFA::where('game_code',$useresponse)->first();`

Comment: When I did that, I got a new error:   ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What are you getting when you insert `dd($games)` ?

Comment: No query results for model [App\BBVA].

Comment: Can you share `migration` and `model` file for `MBFA` and `User_Response`?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comment.

If you want to use the value of `$game->game_code` only for storing to 'game_code' and if there is no use of `$game` anywhere else in the method.

You can simply create a User_Response by:

```
User_Response::create([
    'game_code'     =>  $useresponse, // instead of $games->game_code
    'answer'        =>  $useroption,
    'msisdn'        =>  $msisdn
]);
```